# dSYM file is not uploading automatically while using Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, swift-package-manager

I have added the Firebase Crashlytics SDK to the app

Use Swift Package Manager to install and manage Firebase dependencies.

```
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk
```

Added New Run Script Phase as below

```
"${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run"
```

One more New Run Script Phase added for upload dSYM file upload automatically as below

```
"${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/YourGoogleServiceLocation/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

But it's not working because when test using force crash app. It displays on firebase console missing dSYM file error.

Let me know as above steps are correct or there is any things missing from my side.

Comment: Any solution to this problem?